# Is it possible to use PhantomJS as a client-side library?

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I am currently evaluating different libraries for HTML to PDF export. Some of them do implement HTML to PDF conversion, but it is labeled as experimental.

PhantomJS sounds like a solid option, but I don't know for sure if it will be possible to generate the PDF at client side so... is it possible? how?

Comment: If you're talking about client side, you're talking about browser right?

Comment: if you're worried about server side traffic then you can also use a simple save as PDF link to another server. There are many paid services that do this and return the PDF to the end user in a jiffy. One that we run is http://pdfmyurl.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, PhantomJS is a complete standalone browser. If you like to compile PhantomJS with emscripten to JavaScript and then run it in the browser, you can certainly try, but it would be probably hard to do.

The easiest way would be to have a PhantomJS server running that takes the HTML that needs to be rendered and returns the resulting PDF. PhantomJS provides the [webserver module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/) for this. Of course, you can use PhantomJS with a proper node.js server through a bridge like [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom).

Comment: That's what I suspected. It is anyway the best library I have found so far for this purpose. Do you happen to know any alternative for browser PDF generation? I am currently using javascript at server side too (Meteor). I am worried about increasing server trafic and computation too much if I let the users generate the PDF at the server, since it is the main feature of my app

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that.